# React app routing doesn't load content unless page reloaded

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, typescript, react-router-dom

I've been working on a react single page app and have been trying to get the routing to work.

I believe the routing itself actually works however the page does not load the correct content unless the page is manually reloaded. Back and forward browser arrows also work.

For example I can navigate to `localhost:3000` fine and the content is loaded correctly but when I press a button to navigate to `localhost:3000/contacts` nothing is displayed unless I refresh the page. Once manually refreshed the contacts page shows up. What gives?

index.tsx

```
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
import { BrowserRouter as Router } from 'react-router-dom';

// Import App component
import App from './App'

// Import service workers
import * as serviceWorker from './serviceWorker'

// Render App component in the DOM
ReactDOM.render(
    <Router>
        <App />
    </Router>
  , document.getElementById('root')
)
serviceWorker.unregister()
```

App.tsx

```
// Import necessary dependencies
import React from 'react'
import Routes from './Routes'

// Create App component
function App() {
    return (
        <div className="App">
            <Routes />
        </div>
    )
}
export default App
```

history.tsx

```
import { createBrowserHistory as history} from 'history';

export default history();
```

Home/Home.tsx

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import history from './../history';
import "./Home.css";

export default class Home extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div className="Home">
                hello home
                <button onClick={() => history.push('/Contact')} value='click here'>Get Started</button>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Contact/Contact.tsx

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class Contact extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
              hello world
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default Contact;
```

Routes.tsx

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import {BrowserRouter, Router, Switch, Route } from "react-router-dom";

import Contact from "./Contact/Contact";
import Home from "./Home/Home"
import history from './history'

export default class Routes extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <Router history={history}>
                    <Switch>
                        <Route path="/" exact component={Home} />
                        <Route path="/Contact" component={Contact} />
                    </Switch>
                </Router>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Any help greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1):

I think there's some extra code that might be causing conflict. You're defining the Router from `react-router-dom` twice:

Once here, in `index.tsx`

```js
ReactDOM.render(
    <Router> // here
        <App />
    </Router>
  , document.getElementById('root')
)
```

and then again in `Routes.tsx`

```
<Router history={history}> // here
  <Switch>
    <Route path="/" exact component={Home} />
    <Route path="/Contact" component={Contact} />
  </Switch>
</Router>
```

You have to drop one of them, they're probably conflicting each other

**Update**

In addition to that, I think you should not use the `history` object directly from your export, but access it through the HOC `withRouter`. Then, you'd wrap

So you'd do something like this

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { withRouter } from 'react-router-dom'
import "./Home.css";

class Home extends Component {
    const { history } = this.props
    render() {
        return (
            <div className="Home">
                hello home
                <button onClick={() => history.push('/Contact')} value='click here'>Get Started</button>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default withRouter(Home)
```

Comment: I was following this persons tutorial i'm not 100% on where I went wrong. https://github.com/minioncoder/ReactButtonExample/tree/master/reactbuttonexample/src

Comment: Other than maybe using typescript instead of simply javascript

Comment: So I can move the `history={history}` part into the index.tsx file and remove the Router tag in Routes.tsx but I still get the same results

Comment: yeah, that sounds wrong, you only need one Router. About the rest of the error, maybe you should retrieve the history from the HOC `withRouter` instead of importing the one you're exporting. Similar to [this response](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63819833/1437934) but now `history` will be available in your props; as `this.history.props`

Comment: Would it help if I add that I have an express server running things as well? I have literally no idea what i'm doing lol

Comment: That gives a `Parsing error: ',' expected` on the `const Home extends Compnent {` line

Comment: yeah updated, it should be `class` instead of `const`

Comment: I changed the Home class to a function and removed the `extends Component` bit because that seems like it's the only way to add variables. I couldn't get `const { history } = this.props` to work without it throwing a ';' expected error. TL;DR I got it to work but I can't for the life of me figure out why it now works. It had to have been something messed up in the express `server.js` file. If I figure it out i'll update with an answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue here is that you need to wrap your pages with `withRouter()` like so:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import history from './../history';
import "./Home.css";
import { withRouter } from 'react-router-dom'; //<---------- add this

class Home extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div className="Home">
                hello home
                <button onClick={() => history.push('/Contact')} value='click here'>Get Started</button>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

default export withRouter(Home); //<-------------- and add this
```

You will need to do the same on your `Contact` page as well.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you have two routers?

I guess you simply need to remove the Router either in index.tsx or in Routes.tsx

According to you file naming I would remove the Router in Routes.tsx

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are using the `history` package for navigation. If you are using the `react-router v5`, then you may have to downgrade the `history` package to `4.10.1` until the `history` package developers issue a new release with the fix. As of writing this, the latest release version of `history` package is `v5.0.1`, and if you see a new release than this, you can try with that version first to see if it works, before doing the downgrade to `4.10.1`

Issue Link -> https://github.com/remix-run/history/issues/804